# Merging angled text OCR into lines

Tags: algorithm, text, ocr

I have a text box detection algorithm that outputs word-level detections. Here's an example:
[image]

So the output is a list of boxes in the form `(x1_i,y1_i,x2_i,y2_i)` indicating the bottom-left and top-right coordinates. I'd like to find a **simple decent baseline** algorithm to merge these boxes into lines. So the desired output would be:

`["Hey how are you?" , "I'm great!"]`

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but they are primarily about straight (uni-directional) text, e.g.:
[Merge the Bounding boxes near by into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593506/merge-the-bounding-boxes-near-by-into-one)

My thoughts on this are to calculate vectors from the centroid of each box, and then doing merging of boxes, based on closeness and near-same direction. I'm wondering if there are any such algorithms already out there? The corner cases that I'd like to try and address are:

0. Multiple angles of text.
1. Non-overlapping boxes (like the [I'm] [great!] ones).
2. Crossing texts at different angles (like the two lines above).

I'd like to find a such a quick-and-easy baseline algorithm using python.

Comment: I see no angle or orientation in your box definition. Without it you can not do this... as `(x_i,y_i,h_i,w_i)` suggest just AABB you need OBB ... then just merge boxes with similar angle and order them by distance in the longer axis (along the avg  angle) for example by using `dot` product (it can be used botgh for angle comparison and ordering parameter)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest algorithm meeting your criteria that I can think of.

Define a function `score(b1, b2)` that reflects how likely it is that the word in `b1` precedes the word in `b2`, with lower scores being better (e.g., `0` means that the right edge of `b1` is the same as the left edge of `b2`). For each box `b`, define `pred(b)` to be the box `b'` minimizing `score(b', b)`, and define `succ(b)` to be the box `b'` minimizing `score(b, b')`. Form a graph on the bounding boxes with arcs `b->b'` such that `succ(b) = b'` and `pred(b') = b`. This graph is the disjoint union of some number of simple paths. These are your lines.

I don't know the best way to define `score`, but one possibility is to define `score(b1, b2) = f(distance(midpoint of b1's right side, midpoint of b2's right side) / max(b1's height, b2's height)) + g(angular distance(b1's angle, b2's angle))`, where `f` and `g` are increasing functions (I'd start the experiments with `f` and `g` being linear).

Edit: it occurs that the word bounding box algorithm may only give you a reliable orientation modulo a half rotation. In this case, define `score` so that it's lower when the two boxes are likelier to precede/succeed one another, form a directed graph where each box has an arc to each of the two boxes with which it has the lowest scores, throw away arcs with no reciprocal arc, form an undirected graph with an edge for each arc pair. The latter graph consists of a disjoint union of paths and cycles. You'll have to figure out what to do with the cycles and how to orient the paths.