# How to merge nearby bounding boxes OpenCV

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to segment a web page into a header, footer, left panel, right panel, etc. (get coordinates) using an image processing tool(OpenCV), which is not giving satisfactory results.

I want to get something like this:
[image: Expected rusult]

But, all I got
[image: this]

```
import cv2
import numpy 
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

img = cv2.imread("test.png")
blue, green, red = cv2.split(img)

def medianCanny(img, thresh1, thresh2):
    median = numpy.median(img)
    img = cv2.Canny(img, int(thresh1 * median), int(thresh2 * median))
    return img

blue_edges = medianCanny(blue, 0, 1)
green_edges = medianCanny(green, 0, 1)
red_edges = medianCanny(red, 0, 1)

edges = blue_edges | green_edges | red_edges

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    if currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
cv2_imshow(img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I want to connect nearby boxes, but I don't understand how best to do it.

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wod8U.png)

Comment: You can try iterating for each bounding box and then calculating the distance with every other bounding box. If this distance is lower than a threshold you create a new bounding box that has the coordinates of left-top point with the lower values of x and y of the two boxes and the coordinates of the right-bottom point with the highest values of x and y of the two boxes. Then, delete the two bboxes and add the new bbox to the list. You do this until no couple of boxes center is found with distance lower than the threshold.

Comment: @Doch88 Perhaps you have some examples of this?

Comment: unfortunately not, if I had an example I would have answered this question instead of commenting.

Comment: can you post your original image? I would like to run your code on it to get to the same point as you and start a solution from there.

Comment: @ian-chu added test image

Comment: That medianCanny is actually really nifty. I'll definitely make use of that idea in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I started with your code as a base to get the green rectangles. I filtered the boxes by size to get rid of the big ones that contained large chunks of the image (there's even one that goes around the entire image). From there I iteratively merged nearby boxes until there were no more overlapping boxes. I used the merge_margin variable to set how close two boxes needed to be before they counted as "overlapping".

Each Step (I highlighted the last merged box and the points it found inside)
(This gif is heavily compressed so you'll see some artifacting)

[image]

Final Image

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# tuplify
def tup(point):
    return (point[0], point[1]);

# returns true if the two boxes overlap
def overlap(source, target):
    # unpack points
    tl1, br1 = source;
    tl2, br2 = target;

    # checks
    if (tl1[0] >= br2[0] or tl2[0] >= br1[0]):
        return False;
    if (tl1[1] >= br2[1] or tl2[1] >= br1[1]):
        return False;
    return True;

# returns all overlapping boxes
def getAllOverlaps(boxes, bounds, index):
    overlaps = [];
    for a in range(len(boxes)):
        if a != index:
            if overlap(bounds, boxes[a]):
                overlaps.append(a);
    return overlaps;

img = cv2.imread("test.png")
orig = np.copy(img);
blue, green, red = cv2.split(img)

def medianCanny(img, thresh1, thresh2):
    median = np.median(img)
    img = cv2.Canny(img, int(thresh1 * median), int(thresh2 * median))
    return img

blue_edges = medianCanny(blue, 0, 1)
green_edges = medianCanny(green, 0, 1)
red_edges = medianCanny(red, 0, 1)

edges = blue_edges | green_edges | red_edges

# I'm using OpenCV 3.4. This returns (contours, hierarchy) in OpenCV 2 and 4
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# go through the contours and save the box edges
boxes = []; # each element is [[top-left], [bottom-right]];
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    if currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
        boxes.append([[x,y], [x+w, y+h]]);

# filter out excessively large boxes
filtered = [];
max_area = 30000;
for box in boxes:
    w = box[1][0] - box[0][0];
    h = box[1][1] - box[0][1];
    if w*h < max_area:
        filtered.append(box);
boxes = filtered;

# go through the boxes and start merging
merge_margin = 20;

# this is gonna take a long time
finished = False;
highlight = [[0,0], [1,1]];
points = [[[0,0]]];
while not finished:
    # set end con
    finished = True;

    # check progress
    print("Len Boxes: " + str(len(boxes)));

    # draw boxes # comment this section out to run faster
    copy = np.copy(orig);
    for box in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(box[0]), tup(box[1]), (0,200,0), 1);
    cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(highlight[0]), tup(highlight[1]), (0,0,255), 2);
    for point in points:
        point = point[0];
        cv2.circle(copy, tup(point), 4, (255,0,0), -1);
    cv2.imshow("Copy", copy);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);
    if key == ord('q'):
        break;

    # loop through boxes
    index = 0;
    while index < len(boxes):
        # grab current box
        curr = boxes[index];

        # add margin
        tl = curr[0][:];
        br = curr[1][:];
        tl[0] -= merge_margin;
        tl[1] -= merge_margin;
        br[0] += merge_margin;
        br[1] += merge_margin;

        # get matching boxes
        overlaps = getAllOverlaps(boxes, [tl, br], index);
        
        # check if empty
        if len(overlaps) > 0:
            # combine boxes
            # convert to a contour
            con = [];
            overlaps.append(index);
            for ind in overlaps:
                tl, br = boxes[ind];
                con.append([tl]);
                con.append([br]);
            con = np.array(con);

            # get bounding rect
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(con);

            # stop growing
            w -= 1;
            h -= 1;
            merged = [[x,y], [x+w, y+h]];

            # highlights
            highlight = merged[:];
            points = con;

            # remove boxes from list
            overlaps.sort(reverse = True);
            for ind in overlaps:
                del boxes[ind];
            boxes.append(merged);

            # set flag
            finished = False;
            break;

        # increment
        index += 1;
cv2.destroyAllWindows();

# show final
copy = np.copy(orig);
for box in boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(box[0]), tup(box[1]), (0,200,0), 1);
cv2.imshow("Final", copy);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Edit: The inefficiency of this bothered me a bit. The order that the boxes gets merged in doesn't really make sense. You can see that there are a lot of steps where little boxes are merging into a big box, rather than a big box eating everything inside of itself and growing. Turns out this was a really easy code fix. Since the new merged boxes are appended to the end of the boxes list, we can just index in reverse to make it so that we go from big to small.

I changed the merge_margin to 15 since I think that's closer to the target solution in the question.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# tuplify
def tup(point):
    return (point[0], point[1]);

# returns true if the two boxes overlap
def overlap(source, target):
    # unpack points
    tl1, br1 = source;
    tl2, br2 = target;

    # checks
    if (tl1[0] >= br2[0] or tl2[0] >= br1[0]):
        return False;
    if (tl1[1] >= br2[1] or tl2[1] >= br1[1]):
        return False;
    return True;

# returns all overlapping boxes
def getAllOverlaps(boxes, bounds, index):
    overlaps = [];
    for a in range(len(boxes)):
        if a != index:
            if overlap(bounds, boxes[a]):
                overlaps.append(a);
    return overlaps;

img = cv2.imread("test.png")
orig = np.copy(img);
blue, green, red = cv2.split(img)

def medianCanny(img, thresh1, thresh2):
    median = np.median(img)
    img = cv2.Canny(img, int(thresh1 * median), int(thresh2 * median))
    return img

blue_edges = medianCanny(blue, 0, 1)
green_edges = medianCanny(green, 0, 1)
red_edges = medianCanny(red, 0, 1)

edges = blue_edges | green_edges | red_edges

# I'm using OpenCV 3.4. This returns (contours, hierarchy) in OpenCV 2 and 4
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# go through the contours and save the box edges
boxes = []; # each element is [[top-left], [bottom-right]];
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    if currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
        boxes.append([[x,y], [x+w, y+h]]);

# filter out excessively large boxes
filtered = [];
max_area = 30000;
for box in boxes:
    w = box[1][0] - box[0][0];
    h = box[1][1] - box[0][1];
    if w*h < max_area:
        filtered.append(box);
boxes = filtered;

# go through the boxes and start merging
merge_margin = 15;

# this is gonna take a long time
finished = False;
highlight = [[0,0], [1,1]];
points = [[[0,0]]];
while not finished:
    # set end con
    finished = True;

    # check progress
    print("Len Boxes: " + str(len(boxes)));

    # draw boxes # comment this section out to run faster
    copy = np.copy(orig);
    for box in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(box[0]), tup(box[1]), (0,200,0), 1);
    cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(highlight[0]), tup(highlight[1]), (0,0,255), 2);
    for point in points:
        point = point[0];
        cv2.circle(copy, tup(point), 4, (255,0,0), -1);
    cv2.imshow("Copy", copy);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);
    if key == ord('q'):
        break;

    # loop through boxes
    index = len(boxes) - 1;
    while index >= 0:
        # grab current box
        curr = boxes[index];

        # add margin
        tl = curr[0][:];
        br = curr[1][:];
        tl[0] -= merge_margin;
        tl[1] -= merge_margin;
        br[0] += merge_margin;
        br[1] += merge_margin;

        # get matching boxes
        overlaps = getAllOverlaps(boxes, [tl, br], index);
        
        # check if empty
        if len(overlaps) > 0:
            # combine boxes
            # convert to a contour
            con = [];
            overlaps.append(index);
            for ind in overlaps:
                tl, br = boxes[ind];
                con.append([tl]);
                con.append([br]);
            con = np.array(con);

            # get bounding rect
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(con);

            # stop growing
            w -= 1;
            h -= 1;
            merged = [[x,y], [x+w, y+h]];

            # highlights
            highlight = merged[:];
            points = con;

            # remove boxes from list
            overlaps.sort(reverse = True);
            for ind in overlaps:
                del boxes[ind];
            boxes.append(merged);

            # set flag
            finished = False;
            break;

        # increment
        index -= 1;
cv2.destroyAllWindows();

# show final
copy = np.copy(orig);
for box in boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(copy, tup(box[0]), tup(box[1]), (0,200,0), 1);
cv2.imshow("Final", copy);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```