# create bounding box on meaningful word

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I m using **pytesseract.image_to_data()**
on this image:
[image]

code to create Bounding Box:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Page_2.jpg')

d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I m getting bounding box on each word, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get meaningful word like **'invoice number' in a single bounding box**??? like this:

[image]

Comment: you can try merging the closer boxes by analysing distance between them

Comment: ok, can u plz help me with the code.

Comment: this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490374/how-to-merge-nearby-bounding-boxes-opencv

Comment: you may merge 2 rectangles if tesseract detect so close to each other laterally. but meaningfull part is not easy to understand. Detect the words, if rectangles are horizontally linear and close to each other and then just cancel 2 rectangle and make 1